# Parsing a Ruby Array to JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I have some results:

```
puts result
```

That look like this output:

```
Allowed
20863963
1554906
Denied
3607325
0
Quarantined
156240 
0
```

Debug

```
p results
```

output

```
[["Allowed", 20863963, 1554906], ["Denied", 3607325, 0], ["Quarantined", 156194, 0]]
```

The headers are:

```
status,hits,page_views
```

I need to convert this to json.  If the results was in standard csv format then it would be straight forward but how would one approach it if the results format looked like above?

Expected output something similar to this:

```
[{"status":"Allowed","hits":"20863963","page_views":"1554906"},{"status":"Denied","hits":"3607325","page_views":"0"},{"status":"Quarantined","hits":"156240","page_views":"0"}]
```

**Solution**

```
a = result.map{|s| {status: s[0], hits: s[1].to_i, page_views: s[2].to_i} }
puts a.to_json
```

Comment: What kind of object `result` is? An array? Can you please post the output you expect to get?

Comment: added to original post. thx

Comment: What code did you write to solve this? It's a really easy thing to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
output = "Allowed
20863963
1554906
Denied
3607325
0
Quarantined
156240 
0"

a = output.split("\n").each_slice(3).map{|s| {status: s[0], hits: s[1].to_i, page_views: s[2].to_i} } # => [{:status=>"Allowed", :hits=>20863963, :page_views=>1554906}, {:status=>"Denied", :hits=>3607325, :page_views=>0}, {:status=>"Quarantined", :hits=>156240, :page_views=>0}]
a.to_json # => => "[{\"status\":\"Allowed\",\"hits\":20863963,\"page_views\":1554906},{\"status\":\"Denied\",\"hits\":3607325,\"page_views\":0},{\"status\":\"Quarantined\",\"hits\":156240,\"page_views\":0}]"
```

Comment: I had to update the output, and resolved it by looking at your answer.

Answer (score 18):

Look at `to_json` method.

```
require 'json'
# => true 
h = {a: 1, b: 2,c: 3}
# => {a: 1, b: 2,c: 3}
h.to_json
# => "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You assign your "headers" into the attr_accessor and then tell JSON to parse that symbol. Here's an example:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :content

  def content
    metadata[:content] || metadata['content']
  end

  def self.parse_contents
    txt = File.read(path, {mode: 'r:bom|utf-8'})

    page = Document.new
    page.metadata = JSON.parse(txt)
    page.content = page.metadata['content']

    return page
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!